# Selenium Dropdown

Tags: selenium

Unable to select value "MR" from the Dropdown in contact details page.

Here's is the code

```
public class MySelenium {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\kunal.bhaskar\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    // Form filling on www.spicejet.com     
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        String baseUrl = "http://www.spicejet.com";
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_mainContent_chk_IndArm\"]")).click();
       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      WebElement dep = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTXT\"]"));
      dep.click();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      dep.sendKeys("Bengaluru");
      WebElement arr = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_mainContent_ddl_destinationStation1_CTXT\"]"));
      arr.click();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      arr.sendKeys("Patna");
      WebElement date1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"flightSearchContainer\"]/div[3]/button"));
      date1.click();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
          //click the button
          WebElement arrow = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-datepicker-div\"]/div[2]/div/a/span"));
          arrow.click();

         }
      WebElement arr1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-datepicker-div\"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/a"));
      arr1.click();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

      WebElement dep1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-datepicker-div\"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[7]/a"));
      dep1.click();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    Select curr1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_mainContent_DropDownListCurrency\"]")));
    curr1.selectByVisibleText("INR");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_mainContent_btn_FindFlights\"]")).click();

    WebElement rate = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"taxAndFeeInclusiveDivBody\"]/h4[1]/span[1]"));

    if (Float.parseFloat(rate.getText().replaceAll(",", "")) < 9000)  {
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ControlGroupSelectView_AvailabilityInputSelectView_CheckBoxDefenseAgreement\"]")).click();
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"continue-to-contact-page\"]/span[1]")).click();
     }
   // filling contact details
    Select sal = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"CONTROLGROUPPASSENGER_ContactInputPassengerView_DropDownListTitle\"]")));
        sal.selectByVisibleText("MR");  

}


}
```

Comment: Could you post your HTML mark up for your <select> element? Just to give a bit of extra clarification of what the element looks like?

Comment: Done ..... used selectByValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one suggestion I'd make here is not to use `selectByVisibleText()` method with your `Select` element.

Use `sal.selectByValue("MR");` instead.

Comment: Correct +1 but one can use `selectByIndex` also

Comment: You can, yes, but in this case he was using a string value for the selection which is why I suggested this one.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why it is not working but there are 2 other ways also

but you can use

```
sal.selectByIndex(index of the number of MR);
```

or you can use

```
sal.selectByValue("MR");
```